# How to programmatically change Active Directory password

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have a set of test accounts that are going to be created but the accounts will be setup to require password change on the first login.  I want to write a program in C# to go through the test accounts and change the passwords.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use the [UserPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.aspx) class' [SetPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.setpassword.aspx) method, provided you have enough privileges, once you've found the correct UserPrincipal object.  Use [FindByIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891.aspx) to look up the principal object in question.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain ))
{
  using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName ))
  {
      user.SetPassword( "newpassword" );
      // or
      user.ChangePassword( "oldPassword", "newpassword" );

      user.Save();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's only available in .NET 3.5 and up, BTW (the PrincipalContext and all).

Comment: Remember to `user.Save()` afterward.

Comment: Great solution. How can I also toggle the "User must change password at next login" with your solution above?

Answer (score 22):

Here's a great Active Directory programming quick reference:

[Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C)

See the password reset code near the end.

```
public void ResetPassword(string userDn, string password)
{
    DirectoryEntry uEntry = new DirectoryEntry(userDn);
    uEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
    uEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account

    uEntry.Close();
}
```

Comment: The question is about changing a password, not setting a password. Two different things. Does the user know the current password?

Comment: This is great! I could change the password without the old password. Thanks Dana Holt!

Comment: When you set password in AD, you also have the option to force user to change it when using the temp password. How can I achieve it with the above code? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Try this code. It works for me,

```
public void ChangeMyPassword(string domainName, string userName, string currentPassword, string newPassword)
{
    try
    {
        string ldapPath = "LDAP://192.168.1.xx";
        DirectoryEntry directionEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, domainName + "\\" + userName, currentPassword);
        if (directionEntry != null)

        {
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(directionEntry);
            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userName + ")";
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            if (result != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                if (userEntry != null)
                {
                    userEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { currentPassword, newPassword });
                    userEntry.CommitChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best method for changing password from a web app. It does not create a user folder on the server, and changes the password instead of an admin reset. Reasons why this is beneficial listed here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493571/directoryservices-userprincipal-setpassword-ignores-password-policy-password-hi

Comment: Why catch an exception just to throw it again? If you must, why not just "throw;" so that the exception doesn't lose the original stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
string newPassword = Membership.GeneratePassword(12, 4);    
string quotePwd = String.Format(@"""{0}""", newPassword);    
byte[] pwdBin = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(quotePwd);    
UserEntry.Properties["unicodePwd"].Value = pwdBin;    
UserEntry.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: In my case, I receive the message: "The server is unwilling to process the request".

Comment: needs `using System.Web.Security;` but otherwise works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set a new password to a domain account, by using .NET Framework 2.0.
See working code bellow:

```
string domainfqdn="mydomain.test.gov" //fqdn of the domain
string ldapPath =GetObjectDistinguishedName (objectClass.user,returnType.distinguishedName, args[0].ToString(),domainfqdn);
ldapPath="LDAP://" + domainfqdn + :389/"+ldapPath;

DirectoryEntry uEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath,null,null,AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
uEntry.CommitChanges();
Console.WriteLine(ldapPath);
string password="myS3cr3tPass"              
uEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
uEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account                
uEntry.CommitChanges();
uEntry.Close();
```

it is very importan to check the parameters at uEntry, the code will run under the current thread security context, unless the null values are specified

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ResetPassword(string userName, string Password, string newPassword)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(Path, userName, Password);

        if (directoryEntry != null)
        {
            DirectorySearcher searchEntry = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
            searchEntry.Filter = "(samaccountname=" + userName + ")";
            SearchResult result = searchEntry.FindOne();
            if (result != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                if (userEntry != null)
                {
                    userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { newPassword });
                    userEntry.Properties["lockouttime"].Value = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Password Can't Change:" + ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: unknown parameter `Path`. Does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue in a windows application using Change Password if Set Password was done earlier that same day to give the user a new password.  This happened because our domain has a policy of a minimum password age.  The solution was to also set the Password Change date to 0 (empty) when using Set Password so the user can subsequently change their password the same day.