# DirectoryServices UserPrincipal.SetPassword ignores password policy (password history)

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, directoryservices

As the title suggests, I am having an issue regarding respecting the password policy when setting a users password, specifically, the password history restriction.

The scenario is a user password reset, when the user does not know his current password.  I am using the following to accomplish this:

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "XXXX", "ADMINUSER", "ADMINPASSWORD")) {
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username)) {
        user.SetPassword(password);
    }
}
```

This works against every policy MINUS the password history restriction.

Now take this scenario, when a user wants to change their password and knows their current password I am using:

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "XXXX.XXX.com")) {
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username)) {
        user.ChangePassword(currentPassword, newPassword);
    }
}
```

... which works as expected, and validates against all password policy restrictions.

Has anyone ever had to deal this?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design, as far as I have used it. The SetPassword is intented to act like an admin who resets user password - the complexity policy holds but there are no restrictions on the history. Suppose admin resets your password, sees "can't set the same password" - one of your passwords is compromised.

Our workaround was to allow the management to go through one of our web subsystems only and persist the history of hashes so that the responsibility to verify the history was put on the custom subsystem rather than the ad.

Comment: I was pretty sure this was by design, and that was my planned work around if there was no other way to bypass it.  Thanks for the quick insight :)

Comment: Curious.  I'm working on some.net code that creates new domain users that uses `UserPrincipal.SetPassword()` to set their password, and when the password doesn't meet the domain's password complexity requirements, calling `UserPrincipal.Save()` throws a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` with a message that states `"The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800708C5)"`.  The crazy thing is that the account is STILL CREATED!

Comment: @wiktor-zychla I too faced the same problem. However is there any official documentation around this behavior? Just want to check if this is mentioned in any Microsoft documentation anywhere? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Pranay: this one makes it explicit https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fieldcoding/2013/01/09/resetting-passwords-honoring-password-history-or-whats-happening-under-the-hood-when-changing-resetting-passwords/

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor. In the link you have provided, there is a point saying that  the history check can be applied by using LDAP APIs. Is that possible with the current software versions, the post seems to be old. Am just looking for a solution for password reset functionality honoring the history check in .NET framework 4.0+. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pranay: haven't checked it for a while but if I were you, I would definitely try the code the blog entry provides.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but we never found an acceptable answer. Our systems folks didn't like the idea of storing our own hashes for history. We ended up implementing our solution like this:

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
        "XXXX","ADMINUSER", "ADMINPASSWORD"))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = 
        UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,IdentityType.SamAccountName, username)) 
    {
        string tempPassword = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        user.SetPassword(tempPassword);
        user.ChangePassword(tempPassword, password);
    }
}
```

We reset the person's password to a random sufficiently long and complex password that our code knows. We then use that password as the old password in the change process using the new password that the user typed in. If the process fails the policy check including the password history, we pass that error back to the end user and they have to try again.

Answer (score 0):

Incase the username is not found via the FindByIdentify, you may want to also check it for null first!

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "XXXX.XXX.com")) {
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.ChangePassword(currentPassword, newPassword);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Username not found: {0}", username));
        }
    }
}
```