# ActiveDirectory System.DirectoryServices. SetPassword don't keep in mind history password policies

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm using SetPassword method from System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, to change an user password without knowing his old password.
In my domain, it has a history policies, so I can't use a prior password due this history restriction. However, when I use SetPassword method, it allow me use a prior password, skiping the policies restrictions.
How can I do to check if the password meet wit this policie using managed code or comm?
I have research for a time, but any post didn't help me.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Best regards,

Juanjo.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I found an answer so I thought I'd share:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17495340/4831941

To summarize, SetPassword is intended to be used by an admin to reset a user's password; it doesn't impose all of the normal restrictions because it's supposed to be overwritten soon.

The recommended workflow would be to have an admin use SetPassword to create a temporary password and then, after the user has logged in with the temporary password, force them to immediately change it with ChangePassword so that the full restrictions are applied and it will be remembered in AD's password history.

Further reading pulled from the comments of that answer: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fieldcoding/2013/01/09/resetting-passwords-honoring-password-history-or-whats-happening-under-the-hood-when-changing-resetting-passwords/