# ASP.NET basic authentication change password option after expiration

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, active-directory

We have a ASP.NET website for which users are authenticated using Basic authentication (along with SSL) configured in IIS. The user accounts are stored in Active directory. Currently when users try to navigate to the site, they are presented with login prompt (thrown by IIS) and once the details are entered, they are allowed in if the credentials are correct. All this is taken care of automatically by IIS and Active directory. But we have a new requirement to expire the password after some x number of days and if user tries to login after the password is expired, then we need to show "change password" dialog after user logs in. But I am not sure how this is possible, because once the password is expired and if I try to login after that, then login prompt is displayed again and again. Is there any option in IIS or somewhere else to show "change password" dialog to the user once password is expired (Just like how it works for windows passwords)? Though we can warn the user when the password is about to expire and provide an option to change it before it expires through a custom page, it will be nice to redirect the user to "change password" dialog after it is expired as well, so that it doesn't need to be reset manually by the customer support team.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is **no** simple way to do this.

Forget that you can do this with Basic authentication. This will always stuck and login/password prompt.

If, on the other hand, you switch to Forms Authentication with ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, there is a chance.

The chance comes from the fact that your login form can contain an additional link to a page that allows users to change their passwords. Such page would require users to provide the username, old and new password and would execute the ChangePassword method:

[How to programmatically change Active Directory password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066131/how-to-programaticly-change-active-directory-password)

Unfortunately, the ad membership provider still won't tell your users whether they login/password combination is wrong or the password just expired. A custom provider is required that followsone of these approaches:

[Validate a username and password against Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory/291811#291811)