# How to change OWA password using EWS JAVA API?

Tags: java, android, automation, exchangewebservices

How to change password using EWS JAVA API ? I tried to find solution for it but not able to find anyone.

Comment: I haven`t found any solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

The Exchange Web Services API has no operations to allow you to change a users password. OWA has its own private functionality to allow you to do this but its not a valid target to use programmatically,  basically because your changing the underlying users Active Directory password which can be done via the Directory service API's [How to programmatically change Active Directory password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066131/how-to-programmatically-change-active-directory-password) (eg IIS use to have https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2009/03/16/how-to-manage-my-windows-user-password-through-iis-web-portal/ but this is no longer available in later version of IIS) . There are also a bunch of third party Self service type solution for doing this that backends the same API's