# UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied when changing AD password

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am try to write C# code for update Domain User Password in Server 2012. I'm using following code according to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066131/how-to-programmatically-change-active-directory-password)

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "test.com"))
{
    using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
    {
        user.SetPassword(newPassword);
        //user.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
        user.Save();
    }
}
```

in getting following exception when running code

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I also disabled password policy. Any advice?

Comment: Access is denied => the user the application is running on doesn't have enough privileges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The account your code is running under doesn't have permissions. You have two options:

1. Run your program under credentials that do have the right permissions, or
2. Use a [different constructor for `PrincipalContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext__ctor_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_ContextType_System_String_System_String_System_String_) and pass a username and password that has permissions to set the password:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "test.com", "domain\username", "password");
```