# Error code when trying to shutdown using UWP and C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to invoke a shutdown `if label1.text == label2.text` but an error appears when `Windows.System.ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(Windows.System.ShutdownKind.Shutdown, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` is called.

The error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : 'Accès refusé. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423920/2832222

Comment: No solution it's not for me it's for the Windows store

Comment: did you set the capability in your `Package.appxmanifest`?

Comment: For shutdown i can check what?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Shutdowns the device within 1 second:
ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(ShutdownKind.Shutdown, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

In order for this code to work properly, you need to give an extra capability to your app, open the `Package.appxmanifest` file with *Visual Studio XML Editor* and add :

```
<Package
     ...
   <Capabilities>
    ...
     <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement" />
   </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

If you don't set this capability, you will get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` error when calling `ShutdownManager` methods

From [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.ShutdownManager#Windows_System_ShutdownManager_CancelShutdown)

> This API requires the use of the IoT systemManagement capability. Users can add the following to their **Package.appmanifest**: `<iot:Capability Name="systemManagement"/>`

Comment: The'Capabilities' element in the'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' namespace has an invalid'Capability' child element in the'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10' namespace.

Comment: Did you set the mapping to `xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"`?

Comment: Try adding `rescap` to the list of `IgnorableNamespaces` in your appmanifest as follow `IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap"`

Comment: check this for more details https://codedocu.com/Net-Framework/Windows-Store/Bridge/Error-in-Appxmanifest_colon_-rescap_colon_-Capability-has-invalid-child-element?1961

Comment: @Notwin This API is in `Windows IoT Extension`, it doesn't support on PC. You could only use it on windows IOT.

Answer (score 1):

ShutdownManager API requires the use of the IoT **systemManagement** capability, and the inclusion of **iot** in the **IgnorableNamespaces** list. Users can add the following to their **Package.appmanifest**:, and add **iot** to their existing list of **IgnorableNamespaces**.

```
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot">
```