# UnauthorizedAccessException when using ShutdownManager even with systemManagement declared

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

*Note: not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310257/error-code-when-trying-to-shutdown-using-uwp-and-c-sharp) as I already declare `systemManagement` capacity.*

**UPDATE**: the API is only available to IoT devices, if you want an API for UWP, [vote it here](https://aka.ms/AAi8ncu).

I have a simple UWP app that has both Target and Min version `2004 (Build 19041)`. The UI simply has two buttons Shutdown and Restart:

```cs
private void OnShutDownClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(ShutdownKind.Shutdown, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}

private void OnRestartCLicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(ShutdownKind.Restart, TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

Following the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.shutdownmanager.beginshutdown?view=winrt-22621), I added `systemManagement` capacity into the manifest using the UI, and also double-checked the XML code:

[image]

```xml
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot">
  ...
  <Capabilities>
    <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement"/>
  </Capabilities>
  ...
```

However, I still get `UnauthorizedAccessException` when executing the code, no matter which code I run (Shutdown or Restart). I already tried uninstalling the app and load it again from VS.

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'

[image]

Did I miss something? How do I resolve this?

---

UPDATE: so I tried adding this line to test if I actually have access to this capacity:

```cs
var temp = ShutdownManager.IsPowerStateSupported(PowerState.ConnectedStandby);
```

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.shutdownmanager.ispowerstatesupported?view=winrt-22621), this method also requires the same capacity. However, the code runs well through it. That means something must be missing from `BeginShutdown`:

[image]

---

UPDATE 2: Apparently this API is for IoT devices only? Can I use this API on Windows Desktop device or is there any similar API? Google always lead me there and there doesn't seem to be any alternative.

Comment: Hmmm....I remember when UWP denied full drive access even when it was told to allow it.  I wonder if this is something similar?

Comment: @MickyD I am not aware of this issue. In that case, need to wait for official response from MS. I also suspect this is an IoT device API only and I am running (and intend to use it on) a desktop Windows. Btw why is the `winrt` (`window-runtime`) tag removed? I thought this is WinRT or is it even another platform (I know MS platforms are confusing)?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realise you _were_ actually using a WinRT API.   Generally UWP isn't WinRT. :)

Comment: @MickyD Wait really lol? How come? I thought UWP _and_ WinRT are the same (maybe UWP = WinRT + XAML UI?). I am up for a history lesson if you can link me to it :)

Comment: No, WinRT is the COM-based API originally designed for the early Microsoft tablets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API is designed for IoT devices and the function is not supported in UWP apps. UWP apps are running in a sandbox that is isolated so UWP apps have limited access to system resources and are not allowed to access these system functions like shutting down the device.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Will there ever be such API available? Did anyone suggest one like that, or the team decides it won't ever be a thing?

Comment: @LukeVo You could submit a feature request about this in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select **Developer Platform**-> **API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. The related team will check the request.